# Use user data logged in with firebase on ionic 4

Tags: android, firebase, ionic4

I am a child with an application with `Ionic 4`, my application is already logging in with `Email`, `Facebook` and `Google` using `Firebase`. I created a comments page and the comments are already being saved in `Firestore` and being displayed on a page. Wow do I get the logged in user data and insert it in this page. Comments?

I used the following solution:

JS:
in the builder

```
fireAuth.user.subscribe((data => {
  this.user = data;
}));
```

Methods

```
listarComentarios() {
this.crudService.read_Comentarios().subscribe(data => {

  this.comentarios = data.map(e => {
    return {
      id: e.payload.doc.id,
      isEdit: false,
      Comentario: e.payload.doc.data()['Comentario'],
      Usuario: e.payload.doc.data()['Usuario'],
      Foto: e.payload.doc.data()['Foto']
    };
  })
  console.log(this.comentarios);
});

CreateRecord() {
let record = {};
record['Comentario'] = this.comentarioUsuario;
record['Usuario'] = this.user.displayName
record['Foto'] = this.user.photoURL
this.crudService.create_NewComentario(record).then(resp => {
  this.comentarioUsuario = "";
  this.user.displayName = "";
  this.user.photoURL = "";
  console.log(resp);
})
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

HTML:

```
    <ion-content>
  <ion-grid *ngFor="let item of comentarios">
      <span *ngIf="!item.isEdit; else elseBlock">
    <!-- this rows will represent sample comments -->
    <ion-row class="post-content">

      <ion-col size="2" >
        <ion-avatar class="ion-align-self-start">
          <img class="icon-photo" [src]="item.Foto">
        </ion-avatar>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col size="6">
        <div>
          <p><strong>{{item.Usuario}} </strong>{{item.Comentario}}</p>
        </div>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
```

Comment: Please show your progress by posting some code.

Comment: I used the translator @PeterHaddad

Comment: @Ananth I managed to solve the problem, I will post here